# eliminating repeated values from mysql table

Tags: mysql, left-join

i need help in creating a working joined query between many tables for a project.The problem is i'm getting repeated values when i run the query .If you need sql dump i'm willing to do so

and here it is 
Table 1:-(user) 
The user.user_id table ia a primary one and occurs many times once in different tables and user.uname is kind of primary and occurs many times in different tables(it is not a defined primaary key like user_id) 
1)updates.user_id_u is secondary to user.user_id and can occur many times 
2)updates.account_name and updates.author is secondary to user.uname and can occur many times 
3)group_posts.author_id is secondary to user.user_id and can occur many times 
4)group_posts.author_gp is secondary to user.uname and can occur many times based on different users. 
5)user.user_id is primary to voted_u.user_id_v(table which contains like and dislike columns for updates) and can occur many times 
6)voted_g_c.user_id_reply_g is secondary to user.user_id and can occur many times as the user might click on different links in the page. 
7)voted_c.user_id_reply is secondary to user.user_id and can occur many times as the user might click on many links in the page for updates table comments.

Table 2:-(group_posts) 
group_posts.gp_id is primary while group_posts.pid is also kind of primary for group post comments(it means a comment to gp_id and can occur many times) 
1)group_posts.gname is secondary to groups.name and can occur many times as it is the name of the group. 
2)voted_g_u.vote_4_gid(table for group_posts users like or dislike button clicks) is secondary to group_posts.g_id and can occur many times as users might click on the same like or dislike button 
3)group_posts.group_id is secondary to groups.g_id and can occur many times as many users might post in the same group. 
4)group_posts.author_id is secondary to user.user_id and can occur many times.

Table 3:-(groups) 
groups.g_id is primary and occurs only once, so is groups.name. 
1)groups.creator is secondary to user.uname and can occur many times as the user might create multiple groups.

Table 4:-(comment_update) 
comment_update.comment_id is primary and occurs only once. 
1)comment_update.os_id(original status id) is secondary to update.update_id and can occur many times as users might write comments to the same update. 
2)comment_update.author_c is relational to u.uname and can occur many times 
3)comment_update.user_id_c is relational to user.user_id and can occur many times

Table 4:- (gmembers or group members what i want to do is i want to fetch users of the same group and get their group_updates) 
1)gmembers.gname is actually group name and is secondary to groups.name and can occur many times 
2)gmembers.mname is the name of the user or is relational to user.uname and can occur many times 
3)gmembers.group_id is secondary to groups.g_id and can occur many times 
4)gmembers.user_id_group is secondary to user.user_id and can occur many times as the might be a member of many groups

Table 5:-(voted_u and voted_c) 
1)voted_u.vote_4_update_id is secondary to updates.update_id and can occur many times 
2)voted_u.user_id_v is secondary to user.user_id and can occur many times for the same voted_u.vote_4_update_id 
3)voted_c.vote_4_reply_id is secondary to comment_update.comment_id and can occur many times 
4)voted_c.user_id_reply is secondary to user.user_id and can occur many times 
Table 6:-(voted_g_u & voted_g_c) 
the primary key for both voted_g_u &voted_g_c like voted_u and voted_c doesnt occur to have secondary values 
1)voted_g_u.vote_4_gid is secondary to group_posts.gp_id and can occur many times.

Query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT up.*
              , g.* 
              , cu.*
              , gm.*
              , gp.*
              , v_g.*
              , v_g_c.*
              , v_u.*
              , v_c.* 
              , u.uname
              , u.avatar
              , u.user_id 
           FROM group_posts as g 
           JOIN user u 
             ON u.user_id = g.author_id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN updates up 
             ON up.user_id_u = u.user_id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN groups gp 
             ON g.group_id = gp.g_id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN gmembers gm 
             ON gm.user_id_group = g.author_id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN comment_update cu 
             ON cu.os_id = up.update_id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN voted_g_u v_g 
             ON v_g.vote_4_gid = g.gp_id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN voted_g_c v_g_c 
             ON v_g_c.vote_4_reply_id = g.pid 
           LEFT 
           JOIN voted_u v_u   
             ON v_u.vote_4_update_id = up.update_id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN voted_c v_c 
             ON v_c.vote_4_reply_id = cu.comment_id 
          WHERE g.group_id = 25 
            AND u.user_id = 127 
          GROUP 
             BY up.update_id
              , g.gp_id 
          ORDER 
             BY u.user_id desc
```

if you want to know the one to many relationships its best i give you the sql dump and i'm open to questions.

edit:-
i understand that i'm green and need to learn a lot but i'm looking for a quick fix to finish the project as learning how to make a query will take some time.
here is the sql dump :
http://rextester.com/KRWG51655

Comment: The query looks wrong because it's using MySQL's extended GROUP BY "feature" which allows your to write queries with select columns which are not in the group by.. This feature can cause unrelated data for every selected column which is not in the group by.

Comment: @Strawberry its mysql guys

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions. This is never going to end well. You have repeated values because each of the rows is distinct in some way. If that's not what you want, simplify the problem down to its bare essentials, and see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @GowriShanker Learn how to use `GROUP BY` properly.  This query should error out.  There's no way this query can give any result.

Comment: Do read [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)